# What is an accurate method to measure the C:N ratio of Bokashi pickled/composted kitchen waste?

Tags: compost, technique, soil-test, carbon-nitrogen-ratio

In a container gardening situation without soil to bury Bokashi pickled/composted kitchen waste, it seems viable to add to a tumble composter.

What is an accurate method to compute C:N of Bokashi?

Assume for this question that the Bokashi method is Commercial off-the-shelf style anaerobic indoor bucket-system, with the bucket processed through until completion of the Bokashi pickling/composting anaerobic process.

Assume if answering C:N rather that computation method:
1) Mixed high protein (meat/dairy) and normal vegetation kitchen scraps
2) Normal vegetation kitchen scraps only
3) High protein (meat/dairy) only

Comment: I've tried to increase the precision by asking for either a computation method, or three chief scenarios with the COTS bucket anaerobic indoors systems.

Comment: My Spanish isn't very good, but I think that in [this article](http://tierratropical.org/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=33) they are saying that in one experiment they found 24:1 and in another 20:1

Comment: Normally I try to wait a little bit before accepting to allow other people a chance.  Thanks for the reminder.  I'll delete this comment in a couple of days (or when I get around to it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't the easiest process in the world, but you can do it. Personally, I'd call up a lab and ask if they could test it for me. Other than that, you would have to use something like a combustion process, like a [CHN analyzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHN_analyzer) such as [this one](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/CHNfront.JPG) (expensive), or use a [mass spectrometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_spectrometry) to ionize and separate the material, like [this one](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/06/IMS3F_pbmf.JPG) (even more expensive).

In short, not very practical.